# Allowing user to close message (close button option on top right of message) rather than drupal set message?

Tags: javascript, status-messages

I've seen a few modules use the feature where they have a message displayed, but they allow you to close it by click 'X' on top right. And it simply fades away/hides using JS. (Can't remember which modules, otherwise I'd have looked at their code, and nor can I frame this question right on Google?)

Can I do this using drupal_set_message? I don't think it provides that functionality, as it takes only 3 params and none correspond to that.

How do others do that, because I think it's actually a better feature UI experience, than having to refresh the page to remove the message.

I'm guessing it's by simple js, if people have used in Drupal, can you share the code?

Super awesome points, if any one has figured out a way to wrap this around any drupal_set_message. Because that'd be so cool!

****** UPDATE *************

We figured out a way to do that, but forgot to post it.

In js,

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.messages').prepend("<div class='close-button'></div>");
    $('.messages .close-button').click(function() {
      $(this).parent().fadeOut(300);
    });
  }); 
})(jQuery);
```

In the theme css file

```
.messages .close-button {
position: absolute;
right: 10px;
top: 5px;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
background: url("../images/close_button.png") 50% 50% no-repeat;
cursor: pointer;
-ms-border-radius: 100%;
-o-border-radius: 100%;
-moz-border-radius: 100%;
-webkit-border-radius: 100%;
border-radius: 100%; }

.messages .close-button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 186, 186, 0.38); }
```

Comment: Sorry but this too broad for the Q+A format here. Requests for code to be written are off-topic for various reasons, not least because we don't have code-writing service here :) Requesting links to off-site resources is also a no-no, simply because it's not a good fit for our format. There's a [list of status message modules](https://groups.drupal.org/node/51088) that you can browse, and check out the code. If you get specific Drupal (i.e. not JS syntax) problems implementing the code from those, please just edit the question with that information and flag it for re-opening. Many thanks

Comment: BTW the simple answer for whether `drupal_set_message()` has this functionality is no, is doesn't; if you've seen that sort of functionality somewhere it's been added by a theme/module using CSS/JS, not by core

Comment: Nope, you cannot. `drupal_set_message` is only that - a setter for the message. Now, in your module or your theme you can provide template for message, and a JavaScript interacting with that template.

Comment: probably you are looking for this module https://drupal.org/project/better_messages

Comment: @Clive it have the option to use drupal_set_message() with the help of https://drupal.org/project/purr_messages module, here is the example http://tanc.me/purr-messages-demo. Is any possibilities to post this as answer.

Comment: Have a look at the [code you need to add to your template.php](https://github.com/topsitemakers/ultima/blob/7.x/extensions/theme/status-messages.php) and [javascript](https://github.com/topsitemakers/ultima/blob/7.x/javascript/common.js). Hope this helps.

Comment: @Bala but it can also be done in template itself, it is in the template used in my last project. Or in a dozen of the other ways. It is broad the way it's written now

Comment: @Bala What Mołot said. Questions aren't judged on whether they can technically be answered or not, but in their own right. Don't forget that a question which will simply result in links to external resources isn't likely to be the right type for a StackExchange site. Besides, the OP has those links now anyway so can make an informed decision, and if he needs help with a specific implementation, he knows where we are :)

Comment: Damn, I was just walking to my office, and seem to have missed all the fun. Such quick fire comments :-)

Comment: On a more serious note, thank you for all your replies. I've got a few modules to look at, but for code will now go to stackoverflow.com. Cheers, once again.

Comment: @PratikBothra Thanks for your understanding, much appreciated :)